# Configure fiddler to use proxy

Tags: proxy, fiddler

Is there way to configure such chain MyApp->Fiddler->Web Proxy*->Target Server?

*Web Proxy is one from [this](http://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/) list.

P.S. I know how to configure MyApp->Fiddler->Target Server but I need to test some functional associated with situations when user login from unusual location (for example from Africa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiddler can chain to any upstream proxy. By default, it chains to the proxy that Internet Explorer was configured to use when Fiddler started. But you can also manually set the upstream proxy in Fiddler by clicking Tools > Fiddler Options > Gateway.

Comment: Thank you for reply. One more question: Should I after checking "Manual Proxy Configuration" (in Tools > Fiddler Options > Gateway) enter "https=197.136.41.6:8080" (for example) in first textbox and click OK button for it(chain MyApp->Fiddler->Web Proxy->Target Server)?

Comment: You'd do that if your goal is to only proxy HTTPS requests via 197.136.41.6:8080 and have HTTP/FTP requests go direct.

Comment: Hi @EricLaw i have a quick doubt can you tell how can we achieve the chain to an upstream proxy in c#.

Comment: @RaviKanth New questions should be opened as new questions. If you're asking about FiddlerCore, look at the StartupFlags.